# FT_Read fails, UNLESS reading byte-by-byte where every FT_Read is followed by FT_Purge

Tags: c++, serial-port

**PROBLEM**:
Micro-controller is transmitting 10 bytes(ASCII A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J) in for-loop under debugger control.
Windows application (C++/CLI Code abstracted below) is supposed to receive these bytes.

Refer the two different **FT_Read** attempts, first in while-loop and second in for-loop

**Case #1**: Executing micro-controller-for-loop in one-go, the **While loop** exits with RxMessage array holding first byte correctly as 'A' and rest nine bytes as junk. where fsuccess returned as FT_OK and TotalRxBytes=10

**Case #2**: Stepping in micro-controller-for-loop to transmit byte by byte, the **While loop** exits with RxMessage array holding 'A',0xFF,'B',0xFF,'C',0xFF,'D',0xFF,'E',0xFF. while fsuccess returned as FT_OK and TotalRxBytes=10

**Case #3**: Stepping in micro-controller-for-loop to transmit byte by byte. Executing **Windows-app For-loop** in one go. The Windows-app For-loop exits with RxMessage holding all 10 bytes correctly as 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'.

**Note**: In case 1 & 2 above, the micro-controller-for-loop takes 5 iterations for **Windows-app For-loop** to exit as if '?' and 0xFF transmitted in every micro-controller-for-loop iteration. Whereas in Case #3, micro-controller-for-loop takes exactly 10 iterations to **Windows-app For-loop** to exit, as if FT_Read + FT_Purge removes undesired 0xFF chunk

```
             private:
    /// Required designer variable.
        PVOID fth;
        BOOL fSuccess, fthsuccess;
        array<wchar_t> ^ TxMessage;
        array<unsigned char> ^ RxMessage;


    Form1(void) //Constructor
    {
        fthsuccess = false;
        InitializeComponent();
        TxMessage = gcnew array<wchar_t> (12);
        RxMessage = gcnew array<unsigned char> (12);
    }



    /*PS. All the FT_xxxx calls below are tested for fsuccess before proceeding ahead */
    FT_Open(0, ppfthandle);
    FT_SetBaudRate(*ppfthandle, 9600);
    unsigned char LatencyTimer;
    FT_SetLatencyTimer(*ppfthandle, 2);
    FT_GetLatencyTimer(*ppfthandle, &LatencyTimer);
    FT_SetDataCharacteristics(*ppfthandle, FT_BITS_8, FT_STOP_BITS_1, FT_PARITY_NONE);
    FT_SetTimeouts(*ppfthandle, 10000/*read*/, 1000/*write*/);


    if(fthsuccess == true)
    {
        pin_ptr<FT_HANDLE> ppfthandle = &fth;

        pin_ptr<wchar_t> ppTx = &TxMessage[0];
        fSuccess = FT_Write(*ppfthandle,&ppTx[0],4,&dwhandled);

        /*in absence of Purge below, Tx chars echo as part of Rx chars
        ultimately workaround would be needed to avoid Purging of 
        real time RxData at runtime
        */
        FT_Purge(*ppfthandle, FT_PURGE_RX | FT_PURGE_TX);

        pin_ptr<unsigned char> ppRx = &RxMessage[0];
        DWORD RxBytes,TotalRxBytes;
        RxBytes=TotalRxBytes=0;
        while(TotalRxBytes<10){
        FT_GetQueueStatus(*ppfthandle,&RxBytes);
        fSuccess = FT_Read(*ppfthandle,ppRx,RxBytes,&dwhandled);//reading 10 bytes in one go
        if(fSuccess != FT_OK){
            break;
        }
        TotalRxBytes += dwhandled;
        ppRx = &RxMessage[TotalRxBytes];
        }

        fSuccess = FT_Purge(*ppfthandle, FT_PURGE_RX | FT_PURGE_TX);
        ppRx = &RxMessage[0];//reset ppRx and attempt read in for-loop, the same bytes from micro-controller
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)//reading byte-by-byte in debug steps
        {
            fSuccess = FT_Read(*ppfthandle,&ppRx[i],1,&dwhandled);
            /*in absence of Purge below, alternate characters are read as 0xFF
            ultimately workaround would be needed to avoid Purging of 
            real time RxData at runtime
            */
            FT_Purge(*ppfthandle, FT_PURGE_RX | FT_PURGE_TX);
        }
    }// if (!fthsuccess)
```

**Code snippet from microcontroller below**:

```
    uint8_t Series[10]={'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'};
    for(loopcount=0;loopcount<10;loopcount++)
    {
        UART1Send(Series+loopcount,1);
    }
```

Comment: @BradL any suggestions to resolve the same as FT_Read should work without resorting to byte-by-byte read in For-loop that too with FT_Purge to follow every FT_Read

Comment: Have you tried calling FT_GetStatus(...) to discover how many characters are waiting to be read? Also, in the interests of isolating where the problem is, it might be worth temporarily declaring a local char rxBuffer[11] and  passing that instead of ppRx. That would help you be sure that the problem is exclusively with FT_Read(). You really shouldn't have to resort to that loop reading one character at a time.

Comment: @JohnSheridan I had attempted **FT_GetQueueStatus** instead, edited the original post to this effect. local char array had also been tried with same results

Comment: In that additional code snippet you added it should read TodalRxBytes += dwHandled;  You should also pass ppRx + TotalRxBytes to  FT_Read in that loop otherwise any contents of the array pointed to by ppRx could be overwritten if there is more than one iteration over the loop.  What value does fSuccess have after the FT_Read?

Comment: The fact that you can get data if you purge between each read would certainly raise questions about whether the writing and reading ports are both setup identically. Double check FT_SetDataCharacteristics(*ppfthandle, FT_BITS_8, FT_STOP_BITS_1, FT_PARITY_NONE) is correct.

Comment: @John Kindly re-read the post that has updated code and observations. Regarding the concern on port settings, unfortunetly there's **NO** provision for **FT_GetDataCharacteristics** to double check. Fsuccess returned FT_OK for it though and its single statement setting Port for read-and-write  mechanisms

Comment: You should be able to eliminate the **purge** after **write** by reading the 4 bytes that are echoed back. You wrote 4 bytes so you read 4 back. In essence, that is the same as purging. I can't see anything fundamentally wrong with what you are doing. If possible can you change your microcontroller code to send all 10 bytes in one transmission. Otherwise your receiver **MAY** treat each transmission as a single byte packet. It still shouldn't cause the issue you are hitting but it can be very inefficient (depending on HW & drivers).

Comment: @JohnSheridan Originally it is supposed to be microcontroller code sending all 10 bytes in one transmission and VCP application reading all 10 bytes in one ReadFile. That scheme resulted in VCP application getting first character correct and rest as junk. Incremental problem debugging steps landed me in current situation. First replaced ReadFile with FT_Read and subsequently forcing transmission-reception to be byte-by-byte. I have few more debug observations from yesterday that will be shared as next comment !

Comment: @JohnSheridan The recent debug observations from yesterday follows. Attempt to further analyze Case #2; modified RxMessage and ppRx to type **wchar_t** & increased the RxMessage to be 22 elements. Now, While loop exits with RxMessage array holding 'A',0xFF,'B',0xFF,'C',0xFF,'D',0xFF,'E',0xFF,'F',0xFF,'G',0xFF,'H',0xFF,'I',0xFF,'J',0xFF **if we transmit byte by byte from micro-controller under debugger stepping**. fsuccess returns FT_OK and TotalRxBytes=0x14. Whereas, if micro-controller transmits bytes as chunk of 3 or more bytes the same While loop exits with RxMessage array holding junk only

Comment: Grasping at straws here, but the only thing that jumps to mind is that these might be read event characters inserted into the stream. It's a long shot, but try calling FT_SetChars(*ppfthandle, false, 0, false, 0); during your initialization to disable them.

Comment: Still outcome remains same ! the pattern of junk char remains same in all cases (copy-pasted here). May be it can throw some clue.    `[0x0]0x8441
[0x1]0x100d
[0x2]0xfe14
[0x3]0x8e46
[0x4]0x2421
[0x5]0xfe28
[0x6]0x8441
[0x7]0x100d
[0x8]0xfe14
[0x9]0x8e46
`

Comment: Can you use a terminal emulator to simulate your microcontroller? This would allow you to be certain that the 9600n81 configurations match. Does your program receive garbage in this case? And perhaps you could also try connecting the terminal emulator to your microcontroller to verify the comms with that? If the terminal <-> microcontroller works fine then you are most likely looking at something like an initialization issue for your hardware or a problem with the driver. I've tried to move this conversation to chat but you don't have enough reputation yet to allow this.

Comment: @JohnSheridan Apologies for not able to respond earlier than this. Infact the problem was identified and corrected after posting of my last comment. It related to 9bit protocol being forced by micro-controller. Original micro-firmware is 9bit protocol to address one of many slaves. For development-testing, i had temporary modification to 8bit protocol. Unfortunately, modifications missed the UART mode register that remained as 9bit mode. With boxed/biased mind i kept debugging. Must appreciate that your observation from remote location, exactly matches the fix that resolved at my end

Comment: @JohnSheridan I will explore how to build reputation. Many thanks for your kind support. Meanwhile, how can I help increment your reputation to this effect!

Comment: That's excellent news. Well done! Don't worry about the reputation thing. That builds slowly over time. I'll post one of my comments from above and you can mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check FT_SetDataCharacteristics(*ppfthandle, FT_BITS_8, FT_STOP_BITS_1, FT_PARITY_NONE) is correct. Any mismatch between the two devices will result in problems.